# Native Javascript page loading message?

Tags: javascript, blocking

I'd like a page blocking/loading script that will overlay the entire page and display a "Loading..." message while all the assets are loading, to avoid flashes of unstyled content, etc.

I basically want something like [jQuery's BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#page)'s page blocking method: `$.blockUI();`, but I want it in native javascript so I don't have to wait for jQuery to load (I'm loading my scripts via [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), so by the time my code block executes, I've already downloaded numerous other dependencies for my app, and I get that flash of unstyled content which I'm trying to avoid).

Anyone know of a native javascript solution that might work for me, which I can insert as a blocking (in terms of asset loading) script before my RequireJS call?

Comment: Instead of using javascript to load the blocking UI, you could place some plain markup that shows whatever "Loading..." UI you want, and then use Javascript to replace it with your real UI once everything has loaded.  Even a simple solution like having two divs, one that contains your loading UI and set to `display: block;` and another that contains your page UI and set to `display: none;` and then some basic JavaScript to toggle each one on page load should do the trick.

Comment: Very nice pointed! I updated my answer based on the content `display: none` that you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring your code already with a DIV floating over your page.

```
<div id="loading">
    Loading! Please calm down guy...
<div>
```

This DIV can be displayed already styled to be `position: absolute`, `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` . This CSS can be inline, then it will be applied without any other file downloading. Or, like commented by @aroth, you can just set it DIV to `display: block` and your page content inside another DIV with `display: none`.

Then just hide it with a simple JavaScript at the end of your code (near `</body>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
</script>
```

This script will be executed only after all the other elements are loaded.

Finally, I put this code [here as sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/g7D8e/).

Comment: Hmm, it seems my page content is longer than the window, leaving me with scroll bars when my loading message is displayed. Is there anyway to get rid of those?

Comment: Aph, just figured it out myself: `html { overflow: hidden; }`. My app is a single-window app, so I don't need it to scroll content, but you could easily reverse the CSS when the loading message is hidden again.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to setup a mask with a loading message in the middle using HTML and CSS.  Then have javascript remove the mask and loading message once the page is fully loaded.