# Progress image while page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before I continue:

1. I am aware this has been done before.
2. I searched SO for this before deciding to post this...

Said that, I noticed that in some browsers that have settings to clear cache on every visit to a page, certain parts of my page show with delay. I would like to have a function that will display some animated image until the page is finished loading 100%.

I would like to place it in my header include file once and have it kick in every time a page loads. I think I need it to be implemented in AJAX. I would like this function to be a stand-alone, i.e. not tied to any other functions. Shall I use jQuery? Since jQuery itself requires loading an external file, should I implement it as a simple JS function?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Examples would be priceless.

:)

---

EDIT:

I found a [plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery_loader) that does exactly what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native Javascript page loading message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921723/native-javascript-page-loading-message)

Comment: I did see that post (#2 in my post) and no, it did not help me in any way.

Comment: Based on the answers you are receiving here (exactly like there), what you want different? Since it isn't clear on your question.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if a page is loaded completely? If yes, than I want to show image while it loads and hide it when it is loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921723/native-javascript-page-loading-message

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one too. In fact it is a pseudo solution. It will create a delay whether it is needed or not. I don't want to display any progress image on pages that load fast, but those that are data heavy, I need to stall.

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can do something like this

html

```
<div id="loader"></div>

$(window).load(function () {
  $("#loader").fadeOut();
});
```

You can incldue a div with a loader (have it fixed, or absolute, whatever you like) and then with $(window).load( callback );  you can detect when the whole page has finished loading so you can hide the loader.

Or with pure JS you can do the same,

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onLoad](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/_BODY_onLoad.html) attribute for . Do something similar to:

```
<body onLoad='showLoadingDiv()'>
```

and make the showLoadingDiv function show a full-page white div with a loading sign.

---

Another (probably preferred) option is to have a

```
<div style='background:white; width:100%; height:100%'>LOADING</div>
```

and hide it as soon as the page **completely** loads, i.e. under jQuery's `$(function() { });`

Comment: How to show progress is unimportant. What i need is delay displaying the page until it is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.ajaxload.info/#preview) includes some AJAX progress images to use.

Comment: Strangely enough, that page didn't display a progress image while the page was loading.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      //window.onload will wait for images
      window.onload = function() {
        //find element with id='progress' and hide it
        $('progress').hide();    
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="progress" src="https://forums.embarcadero.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2-21014-135909-1751/progress2.gif" style="display:show;">

    <h1="">This is a solar eclipse</h1>
    <img src="http://www.zam.fme.vutbr.cz/~druck/eclipse/Ecl2008m/Tse2008_1250_mo1/Hr/Tse2008_1250_mo1.png" width="50%" style="display:show;">
    <p>Pretty and large enough to have to wait for</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps