# Detect multiple images load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I'm wondering if there is a way to detect load event of multiple images (particularly, a function should execute when the last image in a given set has completed loading).

For instance, an user clicks on a link and lighbox appears with 10 images. When all images have loaded, loading bar should disappear.

```
jQuery(".lightbox-image").each(function(){
    var image = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('<img />').attr('src', image.attr('src')).load(function(){
        hideLoadingBar();
    });
});
```

This unfortunately triggers `hideLoadingBar();` too early (after one image has completed loading).

P.S.
I also need my function to work after images have been cached so: `jQuery('#img1, #img2').load();` won't work.

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9624426/235710

Comment: @MohammadAdil This is precisely what doesn't work when images are already cached. And I can't `trigger('load')` manually because that will execute `hideLoadingBar()` too early.

Comment: if i'm not wrong load is always an ajax req, did you try progress callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [jQuery imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin, it should suit your needs I think.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that no one has better idea, so below is my solution/workaround. The other answer to this question is probably what you want to use because it's a library created specifically for that but here's the solution that I'm going to use because it's shorter and simple:

```
var allImages = jQuery(".lightbox-image").length;
var counter = 0;
jQuery(".lightbox-image").each(function(){
    var image = jQuery(this).find('.myimage');
    jQuery('<img />').attr('src', image.attr('src')).load(function(){
        counter++;
        if(counter >= allImages){
            hideLoadingBar();
        }
    });
});
```

Works for cached images and not cached images.

Comment: What happens with this solution if you have, say, 10 or so rather large images that are currently loading when this function executes. Then you'll start another 10 downloads of the same images, isn't that right? Perhaps that performance slowdown is acceptable to you.

Comment: Also check the browser quirks [documented on the plugin page](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/wiki/Browser-quirks).

Comment: @HannesJohansson I'm not sure how it does this but I hope that it doesn't load them twice. Especially if they are already cached. In my case images won't be large so it should be acceptable.

Comment: @HannesJohansson I checked this in Apache's access log and even if I create 100 instances of this image, in different ways, at different points, there is only 1 request per page refresh from Chrome 27 (cache disabled).

Comment: @Paul Ok, I don't know how all the browsers work exactly. Just saying one needs to be careful because browsers handle images and caching differently, so if cross-browser compatability is important to you I'd advice to be careful. The people who wrote the plugin thought hard about this and it's not that big a plugin, only a kilobyte minified.