# Images are never loaded

Tags: jquery

I know that waiting until some DOM elements are ready can be done through load of jQuery, however I've never really tested it for specific elements especially images.
Recently, I wanted my script to be able to do something if some images are all loaded (many ajax requests are updating my images container), so I did this:

```
$('#container img').on('load', function () {
       somefunction();
       console.log('somefunction done');
});
```

Although I'm seeing the images on my page, somefunction is never launched.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely the load event was triggered before you bound to it. You should instead use a preloading technique to test if the image is loaded.

Comment: This scenario is documented as one of the [warnings for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/): "*A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the `.load()` shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. [...]*" Which inspired the creation of the [imagesLoaded plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989088/detect-multiple-images-load-event).