# Completing image as progress bar

Tags: jquery, image, css, progress-bar

I saw a web site, in it's load time a image appeared from left to right as progress bar! and under it was a percentage counter.

whole image place was white and in loading time the image in it appear from left to right like a progress bar.

how they can do that? i thought well and searched the web, but that web site i forgot where is that to see the codes. anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You could easily splice an image up into several smaller images and just load the pieces in individually.

Comment: isn't there a JQuery plugin to show it by dividing the width in same sizes and load image by steps in percentages?

Comment: The down vote got me locked to ask more questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that you know when the progress value changes, you just need to change the width of the image (in this case the container div) every time the progress changes.

```
<body>
    <div style="width:200px"> 
        <div id="test" style="width:20%; overflow:hidden;">
            <img src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/careers2-ad-header-so-crop.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

$(function() {
       $('#test').css('width','50%');
});
```

please see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6wtFx/

Comment: Yes, it's a good trick. but how i can control it. how can find how many percents of page is loaded?

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921723/native-javascript-page-loading-message

Comment: and i found pace here : http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/